Adjusting shipping in Woocommerce hook woocommerce_package_rates
I am new to both Woo and php, but I have a decent handle on it I think. I wanted to sort the shipping rates in order and used the woocommerce_package_rates hook. That worked great. My testing site also has free shipping when order total is over $50 and I noticed the free ups and usps plugins I was using did not honor that and kept putting in the prices and methods AND free shipping appeared. So I adjusted the hook call to ONLY leave the free shipping when it was present. Worked like a charm. Now I have one more adjustment I want to make and I cannot figure it right. I have some items in the store with a length > 24 inches. The post office charges way too much for those to ship, so I want to remove the post office rates (I only use ground advantage and priority) if any of the items have a length over 24", just leaving the ups rates (or free shipping if that is the one rate). This is the PHP code I am using and it is not figuring the item lengths and removing USPS rates if needed. Any help would be appreciated....
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates','deal_with_woocommerce_available_shipping_methods', 10, 2 );
    function deal_with_woocommerce_available_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) {
        //  if there are no rates don't do anything
        if ( ! $rates ) {
            return;
        }
        // get rid of rates if free is there
        $rates_arr = array();
        $free = false;
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
                $rates_arr[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
                $free=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // if it is free ship return it
        if ( !empty( $rates_arr ) ) {
            return $rates_arr;
        }
        
        
        /* remove all but ups if longest item > 24 */
        if (!$free && longestItemLengthOver24()) {
            foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
                if (strpos('UPS', serialize($rate))) {
                    $rates_arr[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
                    break;
                }
            }   
        }
    
        // get an array of prices
        $prices = array();
        foreach( $rates_arr as $rate ) {
            $prices[] = $rate->cost;
        }
        
        // use the prices to sort the rates
        array_multisort( $prices, $rates_arr );
        
        // return the rates
        return $rates_arr;
    }
    
    function longestItemLengthOver24(){
        // Loop through cart items
        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            $product_length = $cart_item['data']->get_length(); // Get producct length
    
            if( ! empty($product_length) ){
                if ($product_length>24) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

I tried the above code and I expected it to figure the longest item and remove all but ups if over 24".

Have you tried logging or var_dumping the array you get? Perhaps it's not fetching meta_data correctly. I had similar issues before

Got it working:
    add_filter('transient_shipping-transient-version', function($value, $name) { return false; }, 10, 2);
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates' , 'deal_with_woocommerce_available_shipping_methods', 10, 2 );
function deal_with_woocommerce_available_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) {
    //  if there are no rates don't do anything
    if ( ! $rates ) {
        return;
    }
    // get rid of rates if free is there
    $rates_arr = array();
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        if ('free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $rates_arr[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
            return $rates_arr;
        }
    }

    $max_len = 0;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $max_len = max($max_len, $cart_item['data']->get_length());
    }   
    if ($max_len>24) {
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
            if (!str_contains(serialize($rate),'UPS')) {
                unset($rates[$rate_id]);
            }
        }   

    }
    // get an array of prices
    $prices = array();
    foreach( $rates as $rate ) {
        $prices[] = $rate->cost;
    }
    
    // use the prices to sort the rates
    array_multisort( $prices, $rates );

    // return the rates
    return $rates;
}

